# Improving the default selected item style for WPF tree views

Tags: wpf, listview, selecteditem

Just about every tree view and list item in Windows has an attractive light-blue with border selected item effect:

[image: Pretty selected item effect]

But when I create a simple tree view using WPF the default effect is far less pleasing:

[image: Ugly selected item effect]

What do I need to do to change my list view item selected effect to be consist with the effect in the top screenshot?  Is there some standard / system way of creating this effect or do I need to create it myself using borders, fill effects (and of course the colour picker in MSPaint)

This is the xaml that I am currently using:

```
<TreeView Name="myTreeView" Margin="1">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:NodeType}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" Margin="5, 0" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF TreeView: How to style selected items with rounded corners like in Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047576/wpf-treeview-how-to-style-selected-items-with-rounded-corners-like-in-explorer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047576/wpf-treeview-how-to-style-selected-items-with-rounded-corners-like-in-explorer) thread might help finding an answer

Comment: Thanks, thats pretty much exactly what I am looking for - I was sure someone else would have come across this before but couldn't find a thread.