# TreeView and ViewModel

Tags: wpf, treeview, viewmodel

Anyone can tell me, How do I  implement ObjectBaseViewModel and ViewModel for this case ?

[WPF TreeView: How to style selected items with rounded corners like in Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047576/wpf-treeview-how-to-style-selected-items-with-rounded-corners-like-in-explorer),

I just want to kill the corners from the TreeView but I never have used ViewModel Pattern.

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like his example uses a viewmodel already, specifically in the binding to the HierarchicalDataTemplate in this piece:

```
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:ObjectBaseViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2,1,5,2">
            <Grid Margin="0,0,3,0">
                <Image Name="icon" Source="/ExplorerTreeView/Images/folder.png"/>
            </Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

You would just bind your ViewModel to the ItemsSource like he is doing with "Children".