# WPF ListView: How to style selected items with rounded corners like in Explorer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, styles

This is a link for a question asked before, which concerns a TreeView:

[WPF TreeView: How to style selected items with rounded corners like in Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047576/wpf-treeview-how-to-style-selected-items-with-rounded-corners-like-in-explorer?rq=1)

My question is : How to migrate this Solution on a ListView ?

The answers are a little disordered, so I didn't understand what's happening there !

Comment: What about `ListView.ItemContainerStyle`?

Comment: So, changing the TreeView by a ListView in this code is not a good idea ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought that question sounded familiar. :)

So, you *should* just be able to use the same code, but then use Visual Studio to Find and Replace `TreeView` to `ListView`. Of course there are a few parts like the `Image.Source` and the `IsMouseDirectlyOverItem` helper that you *may* need to alter more carefully. For the most part, the Find and Replace function should work. `TreeView` and `ListView` have absolutely loads of identical properties.

Let me know if you have any problems doing this.

You can change your `HierarchicalDataTemplate` to a normal one like this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:ObjectBaseViewModel}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2,1,5,2">
        <Grid Margin="0,0,3,0">
            <Image Name="icon" Source="/ExplorerTreeView/Images/folder.png"/>
        </Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Let me know if I have misunderstood your problem.

Comment: Always here for save others :) thanks @Sheridan, I did that in the first time, but I had a problem, where to put my 'ListView.ItemTemplate' ??? I tried to put it Instead of  'HierarchicalDataTemplate' but VS said that I can't put this in a 'ListView.Ressources'

Comment: @Sherdian ! I have a little problem: when I select an `item`, and after that select another, the `Item` selected before doesn't come back to its "not selected state".
I think it's because I removed the Condition ` Property="IsSelectionActive" `. VS didn't allow me to put it for a ListViewItem ! how to do ?

Comment: Sorry @Alvaro, I've just run out of time here again... if you ask this in a new question, someone might be able to help you and I'll check when I return later to see if you have an answer.

Comment: Did you ask a new question? I could find one.

Comment: No I didn't, I just answered by the solution I found.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I make some changes and I think now it works Better:

```
<ListView ...>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="helpers:ListViewHelper.IsMouseDirectlyOverItem" Value="False"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsFocused" Value="false"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="helpers:ListViewHelper.IsMouseDirectlyOverItem" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF8F8F8" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFE5E5E5" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#D9D9D9"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>

                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFAFBFD" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#B8D6FB " Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#D9D9D9"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
                <Style.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="Border">
                        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="2"/>
                    </Style>
                </Style.Resources>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
             ...   
            </DataTemplate>

        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.Resources>

            <!-- Brushes for the selected item -->
            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFAFBFD" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#B8D6FB " Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
        </ListView.Resources>
    </ListView>
```

The problem I had with the last answer, is that: IF for example the parent control of this ListView is also a ListView (or a TreeView) when you switch clicks from a listView to another, the last selected ListView always stay selected too... I think because it's independant from the other children.

Comment: Alvaro, while I applaud the fact that you have returned to this question, to provide a better solution for other users, I am not convinced that you should accept this as the correct answer. I personally don't mind because I have plenty of reputation points, but I feel that others could object. When you ask a question, users take some time and effort to answer it. I don't think that it is right that you then add your own answer which implements some new requirements that are not even mentioned in your question. If I were you, I'd have added this as a solution summary update to my question.

Comment: @Sheridan ! It's not about Reputation !! do you know that when you change acceptance you have -2 reputations !!! I did that because I thought that it was more adapted for any other user who will have a problem similar of this ! that's all !, I don't care about any reputation here ! I think that the interest of the users is more important.

Comment: I'll give it back to you because I think you have more experience than me in WPF, so if you see that yours is better, No problem bro :)

Comment: it's not at all that I think that my answer is better than yours... it's more that you have now answered a question, or implemented requirements that you didn't ask or mention in your question. I *did* say that I didn't mind losing the reputation and I'm happy for you to take it back. I only mentioned this because I did a similar thing as a junior member and that somehow outraged a number of users... so my comment was just meant as a polite warning for the future. Hopefully, I have not offended you.

Comment: @Sheridan, thank you ! no worries. I really respect you because you are always here to help others.