# WPF UnifromGrid:How to style selected Child with rounded corners like in Explorer

Tags: css, wpf, xaml, styles, uniformgrid

This is a link for a question asked before, which concerns a TreeView:

[WPF TreeView: How to style selected items with rounded corners like in Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047576/wpf-treeview-how-to-style-selected-items-with-rounded-corners-like-in-explorer?rq=1)

And this is another link for another question asked too, which concerns a ListView:

[WPF ListView: How to style selected items with rounded corners like in Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19227766/wpf-listview-how-to-style-selected-items-with-rounded-corners-like-in-explorer/19249330#19249330)

My question is : How to migrate this Solution on a UniformGrid ? Because I want to have the same effect as shown in the 2 examples, on my UniformGrid Cells.

here is an example of my source code:

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ChildrenList}"  BorderThickness="0"  
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="{Binding NumberOfColumns}" HorizontalAlignment=
                    "Center" Background="Transparent" Margin="4,4,4,4" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Hey buddy, there are no selected items in a `UniformGrid`. Please add more to your question to explain exactly what you want this time.

Comment: Ok @Sheridan, I'll explain more.

Comment: Sorry my friend, but that still doesn't really explain what you want... do you want the `Style` for the `UniformGrid` or for the items inside it? If you want it for the items inside, you could have a problem as there is no such control as a `UniformGridItem` - instead, you can put any `UIElement` in there. The `Style` would then very much have to depend on the type of objects that will go into the grid.

Comment: Yes It concerns the Items inside the UniformGrid... I think I'll remove it and change it with a composition of ListView (Vertical List, which contains Horizontal Lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're half-way there already :)

You need to use a `ListBox` instead of an `ItemsControl` (because `ItemsControl` doesn't handle selection and has no such thing as a "selected item").

Then you use the same `ItemsPanel` as in your example, and the same `ItemContainerStyle` as in the `ListView` post you linked to (*note: just make sure you rename stuff from "ItemsControl"/"ListView" and "ListViewItem" to "ListBox" and "ListBoxItem"*):

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ChildrenList}" >
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="{Binding NumberOfColumns}" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

    <!-- NOTE: "ListBox" and "ListBoxItem": -->
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            ...
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

</ListBox>
```